# Check for extra keys in marshmallow.Schema.dump()

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I want to be able to take some Python object (more precisely, a `dataclass`) and dump it to it's dict representation using a schema. Let me give you an example:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, field
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int

class FooSchema(Schema):
    x = field.Int()
    y = field.Int()

FooSchema().dump(Foo(1,2,3))
```

As you can see, the schema differs from the `Foo` definition. I want to somehow be able to recognize it when dumping - so I would get some `ValidationError` with an explanation that there's an extra field `z`. It doesn't really have to be `.dump()`, I looked at `.load()` and `.validate()` but only the former seems to accept objects, not only dicts.

Is there a way to do this in marshmallow? Because for now when I do this dump, I would just get a dictionary: `{"x": 1, "y": 2}` without `z` of course, but no errors whatsoever. And I would want the same behavior for a case, when there's no key in dumped object (like `z` was in schema but not in `Foo`). This wold basically serve me as a sanity check of changes done to the classes themselves - maybe if it's not possible in marshmallow you know some lib/technique that makes it so?

Answer (score 0):

So I had this problem today and did some digging. Based off https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/1545 its something people are considering but the current implimentaiton of dump iterates through the fields listed dout in the schema definition so wont work.

The best I could get to work was:

```py
from marshmallow import EXCLUDE, INCLUDE, RAISE, Schema, fields
class FooSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE
    x = fields.Int()
    y = fields.Int()
```

Which atleast sort of displays as a dict.